What steps are required to allow a powered paraglider (PPG) frame with motor be accepted as checked baggage in the US?
I'm looking for firsthand experience from people who have transported their paramotor equipment on US airlines.  I have been to fly-ins where people there brought their kit along with them on commercial airlines, so it seems it is possible. The kits are within size and weight tolerances, at least for oversized/overweight checked bags. The sticking point is the gasoline engine. It's possible the kit was checked as "sporting goods", which is true, but if analyzed by the airline, might be summarily rejected, and the trip ruined.
Obviously the system would need to be purged of all liquid fuel and all vapors, which is not hard to do.  That seems to be sufficient for the TSA, but then you need to make sure the airline agrees (see below: " ? Check with Airline ").

Here is the link to the TSA page concerning Engine-powered Equipment Completely Purged of Fuel
The only positions I can find for the airlines are for "lawn equipment", and they say, generally, "if it's ever contained fuel, you may not check it."  But paramotors are not lawn equipment, they are sporting goods.

United offers the possibility of getting a "letter from the company the purged the fuel".  Presumably brand new motors (that have never had fuel) would be allowable OR the fuel source is removed AND the fuel is purged. But the guidance on their site seems ambiguous.
Question
When you traveled with your PPG kit, were you successful getting your paramotor into checked baggage?  How did you describe it?  Did you have any kind of proof from the "company that purged the fuel"?  When did you travel (recently, a long time ago)?  Where did you fly from and to?  Did you contact the airline in advance for pre-approval or guidance? Anything else you did or didn't do?
I'm NOT interested in exploring techniques for how to purge the liquid fuel and fuel vapors. I know there are some techniques (turpentine) and odor masking (dryer sheets), but that's not what I'm trying to explore here. I'm concerned that a perfectly purged motor will STILL be rejected, and how to get around that problem.
I'm also NOT interested in a freight forwarding solution. I realize that UN/ID Number 3166 (Engine, internal combustion, flammable liquid powered), Class: 9, EQ: E0, ERG: 9L may be transported under special provision A70 if certain conditions are met (no liquid fuel and no vapors and fuel lines are sealed, capped or connected to the motor). In that case the article may be labeled "Not Restricted" on the Air Waybill and accepted into the cargo hold of an aircraft.  But a freight forwarding solution isn't what I'm interested in here.
I have spent several hours on the phone with various airlines and come up with nothing substantive; the people I've managed to actually talk with were uninformed about the specifics of this problem. Email inquiries to baggage-specific email addresses have gone unanswered.  There is probably some airline employee that knows the specifics, but I have been unable to communicate with any of those employees.

Do you have any way to contact those people you let who managed to get them transported?

So, you have asked all thing that we may know. Possibly you should try on various paraglider forums (to check how other did it). -- Note: there is also a "mixed freight" (freight done by airline, but e.g. with people following it). I remember to read on Twitter about people transporting part of satellites from Europe to Florida in cabin (just with a lot of hazmat documentation) (but I do not expect normal handling crew know anything it).

@jcaron I had just entered the hobby, was not a pilot yet, and was a distant observer, so I don't have the names of the people who were successful at transporting their kit.  So far the forums I have found do not have not had specifics for paramotor.  There are a lot of people on sporting forums talking about transporting motorcycles, but those go as air cargo due to size and weight.

Maybe get in touch with the organisers of those fly-ins? Also, where do you get info about those events?

Please post your answer once you have it, even a temporary answer in which there are still unknowns might help others.

@jcaron usua.org has a magazine "Powered Sport Flying" that's mostly about ultra-lights, but sometimes mentions PPG events. Good idea. I will also check with ushpa.org and usppa.org to see if they can answer this question (this comment was reposted to fix a link).

I wonder whether the Aviation site might have people who know. I have no idea about its rules so this might be wildly off-topic there.

Aviation SE has several questions about powered paragliders (closest tags seem to be ultralight or paraglider), so it seems to be on-topic there. Although I can't see a specific list of what kinds of flying machines they consider on-topic (you could ask in their meta if you really wanted to know the rules).

I checked Aviation SE and they said "checked baggage" questions might be ok, and opened a vote as to on or off topic: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4500/would-a-question-about-how-to-transport-aviation-equipment-as-checked-baggage-be/4502#4502
